# O que é uma variável escalar?

Tags: php, variáveis, terminologia

Estava lendo a [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-scalar.php) e uma função [`is_scalar()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-scalar.php) - como dito pelo próprio site - quando for utilizada irá informar se uma determinada variável é escalar. Entretanto queria saber um pouco mais sobre essas variáveis escalares:

- O que é uma variável escalar?
- Como funciona uma variável escalar?
- Qual a diferença entre uma variável escalar e uma não escalar?
- Quais os tipos de variáveis que são escalares?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A resposta mais simples é que esse termo, que é usado não só com PHP mas como a maioria das linguagens existentes, vem da álgebra linear.

Em álgebra linear, dizemos que um valor é escalar para denotar um número ou valor simples, e não uma estrutura algébrica. Falar sobre as estruturas algébricas em si seria meio que desviar do assunto, então para os curiosos vou apenas deixar um link para a wiki correspondente da [Estrutura algébrica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrutura_alg%C3%A9brica).

Já em programação, uma variável é escalar se ela for um número, uma *string* ou outro tipo dos ditos "primitivos" em várias linguagens - que é distinto de uma estrutura com mais lógica e conjunto de operações implícitos como uma instância de uma classe ou um *array*. E sim, eu sei que *strings* são no fundo *arrays* de caracteres, mas recebem tratamento especial em quase toda linguagem.

Answer (score 9):

Uma variável escalar é um valor simples como um *int*, *float*, *string*, *boolean*. Esse tipo pode ser acessado/manipulado sem nenhuma instrução adicional, basta chamá-lo, diferente de um *array* ou algum outro que você tem de especificar o elemento ou chave.

Tipos não escalares são compostos ou seja precisam de algo a mais para serem manipulados como objetos, *arrays* e *resources*.

Um exemplo de erro (*notice* no caso) bem comum é tentar imprimir um tipo composto:

```
$arr = array('nome' => 'Fulano');
echo $arr; // Notice: Array to string conversion 

//O correto seria especificar qual elemento do array deseja manipular. Por exemplo:
echo $arr['nome'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi responder porque considero as respostas atuais parcialmente erradas. Elas estão certas em certo contexto. Mas estar certo em uma reunião de terraplanistas não ajuda muito.

O que eu quero dizer, para a ira de alguns, é que PHP tem problemas desde sua concepção até a documentação. Então se olhar a documentação da linguagem isso até se encaixa bem. Mas essa definição me parece errada. Especialmente quando se tenta usar uma definição comparando com a matemática que diz o oposto do respondido.

A documentação não usa o termo em lugar algum mais, só na função descrita.

Para mais detalhes eu já respondi em [Escalar, primitivo, nativo ou atômico ou por valor, é tudo a mesma coisa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575246/101).

Em resumo, o tipo escalar é aquele de valores simples que determinam uma quantidade, uma escala de valores em um vetor de unidades. Ele é uma unidade de medida.

Esta definição exclui *strings*, e até, mais polemicamente, o booleano.

Sob alguma definição um tipo [`Datetime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) seria um escalar. Semanticamente é, mas há dois problemas. Por ser um tipo por referência, em alguma definição, pode não ser mais escalar. E o tipo realmente é `object` e não `DateTime`. PHP não cria tipos de verdade. Embora isso seja mais complicado de analisar.

Pra mim somente `int` e `float` são tipos escalares em PHP, mesmo que a função diga o contrário. Mas para efeito do uso dela, considere o que está na documentação.

Existe um problema até mesmo na pergunta (não culpa dela, é do PHP), já que ela fala de variável escalar. O que pode ser escalar é o dado. Especialmente em PHP, uma linguagem de tipagem  dinâmica e fraca, a variável não tem tipo (até tem um único, mas não vou entrar nesta questão, não é pertinente aqui). Então a função dita indica se o valor da variável é escalar ou não.

Curiosamente o rray fala de algo que me chamou a atenção. Para definir o que é escalar, primitivo ou algo assim podemos olhar para o resultado do `toString()`  (ou algo parecido) que algumas linguagens possuem. Se ela der um resultado significativo então, talvez, dê para chamar de escalar, ou quem sabe de primitivo. Não estou dizendo que esta definição é boa, mas é uma forma de observar. Ela é falha no sentido de que alguém pode criar um tipo que tenha representação textual significativa e não ser nada disso. Talvez posso ser usado com condições adicionais.

Conclusão: não é fácil usar o termo adequadamente.

Eu votei nas respostas (e pergunta), agora não sei se deveria :) Elas não usam claramente a definição de PHP, e sim algo geral para programação, isto claramente está errado, embora a resposta não aceita dá margem para interpretar só como PHP.