# Qual será o resultado de $a?

Tags: php, array

Estava estudando PHP e vendo perguntas, para melhorar meus conhecimentos na área.

Segue um trecho de uma questão:

> Dado um trecho de código escrito na linguagem PHP, como o abaixo:

```
$a = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
$a[] = "e";
```

A variável `$a` irá conter :

> a) e
>
> b) e, a, b, c, d
>
> c) não é possivel atribuir um valor a um array desta forma
>
> d) a, b, c, d, e
>
> e) o array receberá um valor nulo

Então qual seria a resposta correta? Seria a letra C? Porque dá erro, quando eu tento fazer echo $a.

Comment: não se deve fazer echo de um array assim amigo, você deve identificar a posição do array a ser impressa assim "echo $a[0]"

Comment: tudo bem, é pra isso que serve sites assim, todos nós estamos aqui pra aprender e melhorar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Acredito que você [retirou o código daqui](http://www.eugeniosolucoes.com.br/php/adonai/questoes.pdf). E acredito também que você não terminou de ler o documento, porque no final é mostrado todas as respostas, que nesse caso corresponde a **letra D**, mas vamos por partes.

---

A resposta correta é a letra **D**. Pode ver - [como dito na documentação do PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php),  - que um *array* é uma estrutura de dados ordenada representando uma coleção de elementos, e que podem ser iniciados dessa maneira supracitada. Então na **primeira linha**:

```
$a = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
```

Você indica que `$a` é um *array* que terá 4 posições, com outros 4 índices (0...3), sendo então interpretado, dessa forma:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  2 => string 'c' (length=1)
  3 => string 'd' (length=1)
```

Na **segunda linha**, você instrui o PHP à adicionar, na última posição válida do *array*, a *string* 'e':

```
$a[] = "e";
```

Logo `$a` irá conter todas as letras 'a','b','c','d','e'.

```
array (size=5)
   0 => string 'a' (length=1)
   1 => string 'b' (length=1)
   2 => string 'c' (length=1)
   3 => string 'd' (length=1)
   4 => string 'e' (length=1)
```

---

Sobre você não conseguir acessar o *array*, fazendo `echo $a`, é porque `$a` é um tipo não escalar, composto, diferente de uma simples *string*.  Ou seja é preciso de algo a mais para se manipular *arrays*.

Como você não criou o *array* com as posições manualmente, o *array* seguiu o padrão e foi adicionando os dados, sempre após a última posição válida. Então para acessar o *array* `$a`, você deveria fazer algo semelhante a isso:

```
echo $a[posição];
```

No caso, como seu *array*, possui um tamanho igual a 5, você pode acessar qualquer uma das posições (iniciando em 0 até 4), da seguinte maneira:

```
echo $a[0]; // imprime a
```

Se você tentar fazer algo como `echo $a`, será gerado um *notice*, dizendo:  *Array to string conversion*. Leia mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/230295/66203).

Answer (score 4):

Meus dois centavos para a discussão.

A resposta correta é a alternativa D. O resultado da operação:

```
<?php

$a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

$a[] = "e";

var_dump($a);
```

é

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "e"
}
```

que é a mesma coisa que usar a função [**array_push**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php), inserindo elementos no final do array. Neste caso, apenas um:

```
<?php

$a = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
array_push($a, "e");

var_dump($a);
```

Resultado

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "e"
}
```

Comment: Isso se chama aprendizado. Errar é normal. Espero que tenha aprendido algo disso tudo, só assim vai ter valido a pena. Boa sorte!