# Onde é utilizado e qual a importância do tipo string?

Tags: string

Estou começando a programar, porém, queria saber mais sobre o valor e importância do tipo *string* na programação. Em geral:

- Alguns aspectos gerais do tipo *string*?
- Um pouco sobre sua utilização, onde e como são usados?
- Queria uma definição, mais breve para explicar o que é uma *string*? Em poucas palavras para alguém mais leigo.

Comment: `Uma string é uma sequência de zero ou mais caracteres. É comumente utilizada para representar texto ou uma sequência de bytes. Ao marcar uma pergunta com essa tag, marque também com a linguagem de programação a ser utilizada e a operação que está sendo tentada com a string.` basicamente você está perguntando: "Qual a importância do texto?"

Comment: _String_ nada mais é do que uma cadeia de caracteres. Sua pergunta está fora de foco do propósito do site. Boa sorte!

Comment: `Estou começando a programar, porém, ainda não sei o valor ou importância da string na programação.` Você ainda não começou a programar.

Answer (score 6):

## Resposta Curta

> Vai escrever alguma coisa (textos, frases, palavras, caracteres) pro seu usuário?

Se respondeu sim, então você deve saber que **isso é uma string**, por que uma string é uma sequência de zero ou mais caracteres. É comumente utilizada para representar texto ou uma sequência de bytes.

---

## Resposta nem tão curta

Uma "cadeia de caracteres" ou [*string*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science))<sup>en</sup> é uma sequência de caracteres, geralmente utilizada para representar palavras, frases ou textos de um programa.

Nas maioria das linguagens de programação, as *strings* podem ser expressas tanto na forma literal, como através de algum tipo de variável. Quando expressos através de variáveis, o conteúdo da cadeia geralmente pode ser alterado pela da inclusão/exclusão de elementos ou pela da substituição de seus elementos por outros elementos, formando uma nova *string*.

Basicamente é como um tipo de dado e normalmente é implementado através de um arranjo de *bytes* que armazena os elementos da cadeia em sequência, utilizando alguma codificação preestabelecida.

**Texto retirado do wiki de tag** [string](/questions/tagged/string).

---

Como você não marcou uma linguagem de programação, vou dar [exemplos em PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php):

> A maneira mais simples de se especificar uma string é delimitá-la entre aspas simples (o caractere ').

Uma string literal pode ser especificada de quatro formas diferentes:

- aspas simples
- aspas duplas
- sintaxe heredoc
- sintaxe nowdoc (desde o PHP 5.3.0)

#### Aspas Simples

```
echo 'isto é uma string comum';
echo ''; //isso é uma string vazia
```

#### Aspas Duplas

```
echo "isto também é uma string comum";
```

Pode usar variáveis concatenadas também:

```
$nome = "Ygo";
echo "isto é uma string concatenada com uma variável".$nome; //imprime isto é uma string concatenada com uma variável Ygo
```

Pode também armazenar texto em uma variável:

```
$texto = "isto é uma string dentro de uma variável";
echo $texto; //imprime isto é uma string dentro de uma variável
```

As vezes, em palavras estrangeiras é necessário escapar, através da contra barra(`\`):

```
echo 'Arnold disse uma vez: "I\'ll be back"'; // imprime Arnold disse uma vez: "I'll be back"
```

---

E como dito [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231962/qual-a-import%C3%A2ncia-das-strings-e-qual-%C3%A9-seu-uso#comment475354_231962), se você não sabe o que é uma *string*, então é importante que estude sobre, e domine **completamente o assunto**, já que em todos sistemas você irá utilizar este tipo de [variável escalar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230291/66203).