# Como identifcar e quando usar o Value Object?

Tags: design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Estou estudando sobre DDD a partir dos livros do Eric Evans e do Vernon. Durante a leitura deparei-me com a implementação de *Value Object*, eu até entendi o conceito mas não consegui abstrair para uma situação real dentro de um domínio.

Entrei nos seguintes tutoriais e um deles mais confundiu do que auxiliou:

[DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/diferenca-entre-os-patterns-po-pojo-bo-dto-e-vo/28162)

[Robson Castilho](https://robsoncastilho.com.br/2013/11/10/trabalhando-com-value-objects/)

[Eduardo Silva](http://eduardodotnet.blogspot.com.br/2009/05/vo-value-object-vs-dto-data-transfer.html)

A questão é como identificar um *value object* e quando usá-lo?

Comment: Realmente, estes posts, para quem não conhece muito sobre DDD, jogam contra mesmo. Mas, é bem simples usar um Value Object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Na minha opinião DDD tende a complicar o que é simples. Essa disciplina chama de *value object* o que normalmente chamados os tipos por valor, e de entidades o que se costuma chamar os tipos por referência. Entenda mais sobre isso em [pergunta sobre C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

Tipos por valor possuem identidade própria e uma mudança qualquer no seu valor tem-se outro objeto, sem alterar a identidade, ao mesmo tempo que se dois objetos distintos tem exatamente o mesmo estado eles podem ser consideramos iguais. Tipos por valor não possuem objetos associados, o objeto é tratado diretamente no seu local de armazenamento. Eles existem independente de existirem outros objetos.

Tipos por valor geralmente são [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) e [pequenos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101). Eles representam algo único, como quantificações ou descrições muito simples. Os tipos não [escalares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230291/101) de qualquer linguagem costumam ser *value objects*.

Existem casos de tipos que são por referência como facilitador, mas eles continuam sendo *value objects*, é o caso da *string*.

Datas costumam ser ótimos exemplos. Códigos, valores monetários diversos ou outras quantidades, pontos de localização, identificadores, telefone, um dado descritivo simples qualquer (URL por exemplo), etc.

- [Artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object).
- [Artigo do Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html).
- [Artigo da wiki de patterns](http://wiki.c2.com/?ValueObject).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Desculpa Maniero, mas DDD não é uma metodologia simples mesmo, é para softwares complexos e com muita regra de negócio, falar que DDD complica o que é simples é uma opinião superficial de uma solução. Value Objects representam objetos que não tem identidade, ou seja, tem seu conceito dentro do domínio, porém, não precisa ter seu estado persistido, ele PODE ser um tipo de valor (struct) mas não é obrigatório e nem necessário em grande parte dos casos. Se trata de deixar de lado a obsessão por tipos primitivos. https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/07/functional-c-primitive-obsession/

Comment: Sim, a opinião é superficial, uma completa não cabe neste pergunta ou mesmo no site como um todo, precisaria de um livro. Para uma mais completa eu estou disponível para consultoria. Tudo oque for falar sobre o assunto eu já conheço, e de forma geral em desenvolvimento como um todo, afinal faço isso de forma bastante profundo e estudada há 35 anos. O que você falou é uma ideia que faz os softwares serem ruins como o são hoje em dia (o que tenho palestras falando sobre) Um monte de regra que não resolvem problemas reais e que causam outros. Mas de fato não há espaço aqui para ñ ser superficial.

Comment: Quando não usa do jeito que eu mostrei fica pior ainda. E estas metodologias tendem a terem Abstraction obsession que é um anti-pattern que jogam em baixo do tapete porque não atende às "metodologias enterprise", mas que é um problema real e mensurável. Por isso que eu digo sempre que as pessoas precisam parar de seguir boas práticas e aprender os fundamentos e analisar o contexto para usar as coisas. As pessoas tendem a complicar o que é simples baseados em receitas de bolo da moda.

Comment: Eu trabalhei provavelmente no software brasileiro mais complexo já escrito, com uma quantidade inacreditável de regras de negócio e nem passou perto de precisar de DDD, na verdade este teria causado estrago. Como sempre digo escolha seu veneno. Eu prefiro a simplicidade, alguns preferem estar na moda. Em geral as pessoas não conseguem demonstrar ganhos reais usando metodologias mais complexas ou seguindo padrões sem entender sua real motivação e funcionamento e todas implicações do seu uso.

Comment: Isso seria válido se de fato o projeto de softwares fosse uma tarefa simples, e as metodologias de software tradicionais fossem eficientes. Na verdade o DDD pode sim, parecer mais complicado no começo, mas à medida que vamos estudando e compreendendo as razões de tal obordagem, as coisas fazem sentido, e a qualidade do nosso software melhora. As coisas ficam mais organizadas, e você pode reaproveitar o código no futuro. Uma coisa é otimizar o código e diminuir o número de linhas (uma abordagem antiga em desuso). Outra coisa é organizar o software e todo o processo de desenvolvimento. Seja Ágil

Comment: @RicardodaRochaVitor Eu "adoro" crenças. O dia que alguém apresentar uma prova que um projeto feito por pessoas competentes é melhor em um sentido geral se usar DDD, aí eu "acredito". Eu peço isso e as pessoas só falam o que acham. Eu não posso adotar uma ferramenta só porque outras pessoas usam e dizem que é bom. Quero ver todos os dados, eu adotarei se o as provas apresentadas foram nas mesmas circunstâncias dos projetos que eu faço (que por sinal é o que quase todo mundo faz), também não posso trabalhar com exceções. Senão cai em "terraplanismo".

Answer (score 1):

Então jovem, não é tão complicado ou místico assim...

pra ajudar, o sujeito da DevMedia cita a wikipedia... e ainda diz nada com coisa nenhuma.. ok...

1. Pense de forma simples, na IMUTABILIDADE do objeto. O objeto de valor, portanto, NÃO MUDA no contexto da sua aplicação;
2. que tal, se a gente pensar num lista de serviços, por exemplo? [serviços](https://www.receita.pb.gov.br/ser/announcements/4111-receita-estadual-implanta-novos-codigos-para-servicos-de-taxas)
3. veja que os serviços que você disponibiliza para incluir em uma nota fiscal normalmente não mudam, certo? (dificilmente o governo altera esse tipo de lista)

@JcSaint, pense no software de maneira mais leve, e mais fluida. O software que escrevemos primeiramente serve a nós, programadores.

;-)

Answer (score 1):

Muito resumidamente é o seguinte:

- **Entidades** possuem Identificação - **Id**. Ex: Cliente.
- **Valores** não possuem Identificação. Ex: Site do Cliente.

Veja o seguinte:

```
cliente: {
    id: 1,
    nome: "Thiago Lunardi",
    sites: [
        { url: "http://thiagolunardi.net", tipo: "blog" },
        { url: "https://github.com/thiagolunardi", tipo: "github" },
    ]
}
```

Cliente possui identificação, mas Sites já não possuem identificação, são apenas valores.

Answer (score 1):

Uma objeto de valor trabalha com agregação. Duas regras importantes:
1) Eles não têm identidade;
2) Eles são imutáveis;

O que isso significa: Se você tem um cliente e ele só tem um endereço completo, e o endereço só existe enquanto existir o cliente... isso é uma agregação, logo, pode ser um objeto de valor.
Se você utilizar um Banco de Dados Relacional, um objeto de valor está intrinsecamente dentro da entidade pai, ou seja, endereço (rua, logradouro, bairro, CEP e etc) vive dentro da Entidade Cliente. Porém, caso seu negócio permita que o cliente tenha mais de um endereço, então não teremos mais a exclusividade do domínio e ele não pode ser um objeto de valor, mas uma classe ou entidade participando de um relacionamento e com isso terá um ID e não ser imutável.