# Qual a diferença entre o VO (Value Object) e o DTO (Data Transfer Object)

Tags: terminologia, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software

Qual a diferença entre um VO e um DTO, e como identificar quando devo utilizar cada um deles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DTO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305301/101), como o próprio nome diz, é um objeto com dados sendo transferidos entre memória e persistência. Ele costuma ser uma classe com todos os campos de um modelo e geralmente não tem comportamentos, só estado. Pode ser grande e complexo e não costuma ter identidade, ou seja, se mudar algo nele, tudo bem, continua sendo o mesmo objeto, portanto semântica típica de referência. Por exemplo, um cliente ou produto poderiam ser representados em determinado momento da aplicação com o DTO. É um objetivo de mecanismo.

[Value Object](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232955/101) é algo bem mais simples e que representa um valor único, por exemplo um telefone, um e-mail, uma quantidade. Ele tem identidade e mudar alguma coisa nele passa ser outro objeto, portanto semântica típica de valor. Nas linguagens que permitem, de fato ele é por valor e não uma classe. Há casos que pode ter comportamento.

Isto pode ajudar entender embora não seja a mesma coisa: [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101). Há uma relação conceitual entre a classe e o DTO e a estrutura e o VO, não que elas precisam estar ligadas, até porque tem linguagem que sequer tem `struct`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: mas VO é usada no mesmo contexto que DTO, ou faz parte do dominio e é usado ali junto com as entidades?

Comment: Vo fará parte de uma entidade, não dá pra comparar muito VO com DTO, ainda que esteja na pergunta :)