# Quais as diferenças entre Value Objects e entidades na orientação a objetos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, terminologia, objetos

Gostaria de saber quais são as diferenças entre os conceitos de Value Objects e entidades na orientação a objetos.

OBS: A questão não é se o uso desses conceitos são bons ou não, a dúvida é em relação a diferença conceitual desses tipos de objetos.

Comment: Em resumo VOs são utilizados para trafegar informações entre camadas da aplicação, e entidades são utilizadas para persistência na base de dados.

Comment: Não só pra isso. Eu diria que a imutabilidade é a característica principal de um VO ao contrário da entidade que é mutável. Além disso, você pode ter VO que não será usado para trafegar dados entre camadas e você também pode ter entidades mesmo quando não estiver usando nenhuma persistência. É um conceito básico de Modelo de Entidade Relacionamento, mais específico da Agregação x Composição. Eric Evans tentou explicar de um jeito mais objetivo para programadores OOP e resolveu dar um nome diferente, acabou confundindo mais!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A questão não é se o uso desses conceitos são bons ou não, a dúvida é em relação a diferença conceitual desses tipos de objetos.

Diferença é a **Mutabilidade**.

O que vai ser Entidade ou Value Object depende da modelagem que você vai fazer.

Se um objeto dentro do domínio do seu sistema pode mudar de estado, então você vai precisar de um identificador único para ele (ID) e ele será uma Entidade.

Se um objeto dentro do seu domínio não guarda estado e não precisa existir se não estiver relacionado com nenhuma outra Entidade, então considere-o como forte concorrente a ser um VO.

Ex:

Pessoa é uma entidade, pois mesmo que ela mude de nome, endereço ou e-mail. Ela continua sendo a mesma pessoa!

Nome, Endereço e E-Mail são VO pois, depois de serem alterados, os novos são importantes e os antigos não servem para mais nada, podem ser descartados pois não estão mais sendo referenciados. A alteração de um VO significa substituir por um novo sobrescrevendo o antigo.

Algumas linguagens de programação tratam dados dos tipos `String` ou `int` como objetos de valor imutáveis, e se você sabe como funciona o manuseio desses tipos nessas linguagens, talvez isso ajude a entender melhor porque essa diferença na orientação a objetos.

Comment: E a relação com a persistência? As entidades não seriam os objetos que são salvos no banco? Não é por isso a presença do identificador que seria correspondente ao id de uma tabela do banco?. O comentário feito de um usuário na minha pergunta fala algo relacionado a isso, poderia abordar essa questão para complementar a sua resposta?

Comment: Sim, com certeza. Esse é um dos motivos de toda entidade precisar ter um identificador que normalmente também é usado como id de uma tabela em bancos de dados relacionais. Mas pense pra quê o ID é útil no banco de dados? Se as entidades fossem imutáveis poderíamos criar um hash de todos os valores de seus campos e isso seria seu identificador, concorda?

Acho que pode te ajudar fixar o conceito de entidade para persistência em banco de dados relacional dando uma olhada em diferença entre relacionamento Agregação x Composição.

Answer (score 4):

Já [respondi sobre VO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232955/101).

Entidades são todo o resto, ou seja, elas são mutáveis, por referência sempre, e costumam ser compostos por vários outros objetos, sejam VOs ou outras entidades, e algo importante é que para elas terem identidade precisam de um identificador porque o objeto em si não possui identidade. Elas existem apenas porque existem outros objetos para o compor, e uma mudança em alguma parte do seu estado não o torna outro objeto, ele continua sendo igual se o identificador for igual. Pra todos os efeitos são as classes que as pessoas conhecem em orientação a objeto, mas algumas linguagens obrigam e em alguns casos é necessário que os VOs sejam classes.

Exemplos típicos são um Cliente, um Produto, uma Nota Fiscal. Em geral o pessoal não estranha muito porque é a classe que eles conhecem, o VO parece algo confuso porque a maioria começou aprender programar OOP sem entender os conceitos fundamentais da computação, mas eles são simples.

Uma das críticas que eu faço para o DDD é que ele pressupõe um pouco a tecnologia que está sendo usada, e uma que nem sempre corresponde a realidade. Ele fez sentido em Java, mas por alguma razão a parte da comunidade de C# adotou, sendo uma linguagem que faz menos sentido usar DDD. O VO funciona de forma automática em C# desde que a pessoa programe de forma adequada.

Um ponto que eu vejo como errado é o pessoal falar que entidade tem identidade. Na verdade não tem, tanto é que precisa de um identificador. O objeto ter identidade significa que o seu valor integralmente diz o que o objeto é. Eles até usam o conceito certo, mas dão um nome ruim. Quando você precisa de um *value object* específico (o identificador) para dar identidade para aquela entidade é porque a entidade como um todo não tem identidade própria, precisa de um artifício para dar a identidade para ela.

Então em uma entidade se tiver dois objetos completamente diferentes um do outro exceto pelo identificador, é a mesma entidade. Estranho, não? Isso faz sentido para o que DDD propõe, e é um dos motivos que não gosto.

A parte que eu gosto em DDD é que obrigar ter um identificador ajuda a modelar de forma relacional. Curiosamente o resto não ajuda. Objetos de valor não precisam ser relacionados, eles ficam dentro de entidades de forma natural.

Grosso modo é isto. Já li muito sobre o assunto e cada um tem detalhes específicos que variam dependendo de quem está falando, então não podemos dizer que tem um conhecimento universal que vão além dessas características básicas.