# Devemos criar DTOs que sejam iguais as Entidades

Tags: api, asp.net-core, arquitetura-de-software

Estou criando uma API ao estilo REST e usando *Clean Architecture*. Tenho na minha Library de Core uma pasta para os meus *Input Models* e *View Models*.

**Precisa criar *Input* e *View Models*, mesmo que essas sejam exatamente iguais a Entidade?**

Acredito que talvez não tenha uma regra geral sobre isso, mas se poderem dizer-me o que vocês costumam fazer, já ajudaria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim.

Você na verdade poderia até ter mais objetos que parecem repetidos, mas, conceitualmente não são.

Para exemplificar, você poderia ter:

**Modelos de domínio**, isto é, os objetos que vão conter as regras e invariantes que dão sentido/fazem diferença pro seu "negócio". Eles representam algo no domínio.

**Value Object**, isto é, objetos que não possuem identidade, eles medem, quantificam ou descrevem "coisas".

**DTOs**, isto é, objetos que não possuem nenhum tipo de comportamento. Sua função é obter e armazenar dados.

Os DTOs são usados em camadas mais infraestruturais mesmo, como persistência, interação com portas HTTP, Kafka e etc.
O ganho ao partir para este tipo de abordagem, é que caso precise alterar algo na sua implementação, que não tenha nada a ver com o negócio, seus modelos de domínio estarão intactos.

- [O que é um DTO?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31362/o-que-%C3%A9-um-dto/31365#31365)
- [Como identifcar e quando usar o Value Object?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232955/como-identifcar-e-quando-usar-o-value-object)