# Onde os dados são colocados na memória em C?

Tags: c, c++, memória

Considerando que a memória é dividida em quatro segmentos: dados, *heap*, pilha e código, onde as variáveis globais, variáveis estáticas, dados constantes, variáveis locais, ponteiros e o espaço alocado dinamicamente são armazenados na memória?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) globais ou estáticas locais precisam estar disponíveis por todo [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) da aplicação. Estamos falando do espaço na memória e não necessariamente ao objeto. Então é preciso uma área especial chamada [*data segment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment).

Mesmo esta área tem duas partes distintas. A área de dados não inicializados ou BSS (Block Started by Symbol), e a área de dados já inicializados no executável.

E aqui a resposta começa complicar, porque na área não inicializada esses dados podem ter [ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101) e [constantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203151/101) que a pergunta se refere, então em parte já respondo outras coisas. Pode ter dados que só vão existir durante a execução, incluindo ponteiros.

É importante notar que toda variável global é estática e apenas algumas variáveis locais são estáticas (declaradas explicitamente). Elas não precisam ser imutáveis e não precisam ter seu valor prévio antes da execução.

Mas alguns casos o valor já é inicializado. Aí tem a área de dados chamada *data segment* cujo espaço é reservado no executável e os dados já estão lá, portanto é uma área somente de leitura. Pode ter os mesmos tipos de dados ali, incluindo ponteiros e constantes.

A área chamada de [*code segment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) tem códigos e algumas constantes que podem ser tratadas como parte do código. Em geral são constantes simples, em geral [escalares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230291/101). Esta área não pode ter variáveis, até por ser apenas de leitura (existe a possibilidade de escrever nela em situações excepcionais) e com valor previamente conhecido.

Quando a constante é um pouco mais complexa é necessário [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) e pode ter um ponteiro ali para a constante que efetivamente está no *data segment*. *Strings* por exemplo não costumam estar na área do código, mas possuem um ponteiro para a área de dados onde tem o texto.

Até aqui o programador não pode interferir diretamente (a não ser quando diz que quer que a variável local seja estática), normalmente já está definido pela implementação como será, em alguns casos com alguma configuração possível.

Já dados potencialmente mutáveis com tempo de vida limitado precisam ir para a [*stack* ou *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Esses dados não são constantes, mas podem ser [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), podem ser ponteiros que apontam para qualquer área da aplicação em execução (tentativas de acessar outras áreas resultará em erro).

A escolha entre a pilha e o monte é se o tempo de vida equivale ao tempo de vida de uma função. Quando ele encaixa com a execução da função pode por na pilha, se a duração for maior e o objeto se mantém vivo depois do fim da função ele precisa ir para o *heap*, através das funções referidas na pergunta. É aqui onde o programador precisa decidir onde vai.

Mas objetos muito grandes ou com tamanho não determinado previamente também precisam ir para o *heap*. [Isto já foi respondido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101). Por isso boa parte dos objetos não simples/escalares vão para lá.

Podem ter ponteiros nas duas áreas. Ponteiros são dados escalares([?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575246/101)).

[image: Diagrama com as áreas de memória]

Note que isso é o mais comum, mas depende de implementação, C ou C++ não obriga ser assim.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).