# Escalar, primitivo, nativo ou atômico ou por valor, é tudo a mesma coisa entre tipos de dados?

Tags: terminologia, tipagem, engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-computadores

Qual a relação entre estes tipos de dados usados em computação? O que os diferencia? São sinônimos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pergunta é boa até para eu rever alguns conceitos, consolidando o certo e reconsiderando o que aprendi errado. Esta é a beleza do Stack Overflow.

## Atômico

De fato [já respondi sobre ele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253852/101) e acho que é uma boa resposta. Ele é o tipo de dado que pode ser manipulado de forma integral em uma operação simples e indivisível, ele faz a operação por completo, ou não faz.

Em tese qualquer tipo poderia ser assim, mas na prática somente alguns tipos muito simples são, porque seria difícil e até ineficiente tornar tudo atômico. Aí eles se confundem com os tipos nativos que também são muito simples e por ser nativo é fácil realizar a atomicidade. Nem todo tipo nativo precisa ser atômico.

Um tipo pode ser atômico pela sua construção geral, mesmo não sendo simples, quase sempre à custa de complexidade e ineficiência. Mas imagino que o termo neste contexto seja usado apenas para os tipos que podem ser naturalmente atômicos.

## Nativo

É aquele cuja arquitetura que está rodando entende diretamente sem precisar acumular instruções diferentes para manipulá-lo. Justamente por isso ele costuma ser atômico.

Esses tipos costumam ser apenas numéricos e com um tamanho limitado, geralmente igual ou menor que uma [palavra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101) da arquitetura. Se ultrapassar o tamanho de uma palavra tende a não ser atômico. Então eles costumam ser desde valores booleanos até ponteiros, passando por vários tamanhos de inteiros ou numéricos com ponto flutuante (quase sempre binários). Por isso eles costumam ter até 8 bytes na maioria das arquiteturas modernas, e em alguns casos existem instruções vetoriais que podem ir até além, muitas vezes atomicamente.

Mesmo uma data e/ou hora pode ser representado com o tipo nativo, ainda que ele possua uma abstração. Porém eu tenho a impressão que, não consegui achar uma fonte que cravasse, que esse tipo em si não é nativo. Existem algumas questões desses tipos que precisam ser tratadas além do que o processador é capaz de fazer. Verdade seja dita, mesmo um simples `int` que a maioria das linguagens possuem precisa de algo extra em alguns pontos. Mas acredito que um tipo sobre o ponto na linha do tempo seja necessário em seu fundamento, por isso ele não seria nativo.

Isso vale para outros tipos assim. Então acho que se não há um mapeamento direto o tipo já não é nativo. Sei que dá margem para controvérsia. Não consigo traçar uma linha considerada universal aqui.

Note que um caractere de texto não deixa de ser um número com uma representação gráfica diferente. E uma *string* é um *array* de caracteres, portanto um dado composto e bem mais complexo, que o processador não costuma manipular diretamente (até mesmo com otimizações vetoriais não consegue) e por isso não deve ser atômico.

Muitas linguagens não aproveitam completamente todas as possibilidades de tipos nativos ou fazem abstrações até mesmo onde é possível mapear diretamente.

Vi alguma definição isolada que nativo é o mesmo que *built-in* (veja abaixo) em oposição a ser providenciada pela biblioteca, o que seria sinônimo do primitivo sob algumas definições. Não gosto desta definição.

## Escalar

Sempre considerei ele como um tipo simples. Ele até é, mas o nome já diz mais que isso. Não é só ser simples, ele também precisa ter... escala. E se eu estiver certo agora, algumas respostas dadas em [pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230291/101) estão erradas, pelo menos parcialmente.

Pra mim *string* nunca foi um dado escalar. O que eu achava que era escalar era o caractere, mas até isso eu já acho que pode não ser, assim como o booleano. *String* não é um tipo simples. Um booleano é, mas não é usado para dar escala para alguma coisa. Se uma *string* é, então *array* também, pelo menos em algumas circunstâncias, parece bem errado, parece ser o oposto.

Então precisamos de uma definição melhor para entender o que é.

Na parte fácil temos que entender que o termo não é o mesmo que ser nativo ou atômico. Não vou comparar ainda com o primitivo porque explicarei sobre ele depois. É possível ter um tipo nativo e/ou atômico e não ser escalar, e um tipo pode ser escalar mesmo não sendo atômico e/ou nativo. Um tipo decimal pode ser um exemplo do último e o booleano exemplo do primeiro.

Então entre [`Boolean` e `boolean` do Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160914/101), qual(is) são escalares e qual(is) não? O fato de ser por referência impede de ser escalar já que há alguma composição (referência + valor) na implementação? Não é só uma questão de semântica?

Não encontrei nada que seja canônico que um booleano não seja escalar. Alguns podem considerar uma escala muito simples, mesmo sem magnitude, mas alguns consideram que não é escala, é apenas escolha lógica.

Pelo que entendi um tipo complexo (do conceito matemático mesmo) não é escalar, por não usar só números reais. Se um complexo não é escalar, o booleano provavelmente não deveria ser, já que apenas por acaso ele pode ser representado por um número real, mas a semântica sequer é numérica.

Se emprestarmos a [definição matemática do termo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)) dá a ideia que data, tipo flutuante ou ponto fixo decimal sejam escalares, mesmo eles não sendo nativos ou até mesmo atômicos. Não dá margem, no meu entendimento, que seja um conjunto de dados enorme, nem mesmo que seja algo que não seja uma medida, como um caractere, que fique claro, não é uma medida (alguns poderão dizer que pode ser visto assim sob certo ponto de vista).

Então consigo dar uma definição melhor? Claro que sim, mesmo sem ter certeza absoluta. Me parece que em programação adotamos o [conceito usado pela física](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(physics)) e não matemática. Ele fala justamente de unidades de medida, que demonstrem quantidade, escala. Lá diz até que um valor escalar em física é um valor escalar em matemática, e me deixa confuso novamente. Não me parece que eles se encaixam, que a física seja um *superset* da matemática, parece mais ser um *subset*, algo mais restritivo, já que fala em unidades de medida. Mas pode ser apenas textos não tão bons.

A definição usada, bem acanhadamente, [na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_processor#Scalar_data_type) para a computação é a que está nas respostas lá da pergunta, mas desde que quando a Wikipedia é um lugar só de informação correta e canônica, especialmente em computação? A coisa é tão grave que ele define que é um valor não composto, mas inclui a *string*, que claramente é um valor composto. Note não ter nenhuma referência para aquilo.

E no fim eu agora tenho mais dúvidas que certezas sobre a definição correta. Adoraria que alguém postasse uma resposta definitiva. As fontes que eu costumo usar não ajudaram. Não sei o que farei daqui pra frente. Sei que muda pouco na prática, mas não gosto de usar termos equivocadamente. E não quero ter que explicar o que estou querendo dizer toda vez que usar o termo. Provavelmente vou usar o termo para coisas simples, numéricas, que possuem escala. Lamento por quem entender outra coisa. Me parece que a maioria das pessoas usam errado na computação. No mínimo deveríamos usar menos, porque quer dizer coisas diferentes para pessoas diferentes.

## Primitivo

Aí começa complicar. Eu já respondi em vários lugares e até em [minha "resposta canônica" sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101). Ali eu dou duas definições: que ele é o mesmo que o nativo; que ele é tratamento especial da linguagem.

Acho que não deveria ser sinônimo de outra coisa e aqui preciso rever minha resposta. Chego falar que eles são tipos escalares, o que faria ser sinônimo. E dá a ideia que eles são nativos, na definição que mais vejo as pessoas usarem.

A resposta também mostra a escola que diz que é sobre a linguagem dar tratamento especial. E apesar dessa escola ser menos usada em todos lugares que eu vejo, não quer dizer que ela esteja menos certa. Ter o erro em muitos lugares não faz ele deixar de ser erro. Não estou dizendo que esta definição é mais certa que a anterior, mas meu TOC (bom ter isso em mente) está me dizendo que o termo deveria ser diferente. Então estou propenso a aceitar mais a questão do tratamento especial.

Por essa última definição, *string* é um dado primitivo. O mesmo valeria para uma tupla em C# e algumas outras linguagens. Mas não sei até onde vai. Porque vários tipos possuem tratamento especial em algum nível. Em boa parte das linguagens que possuem otimização, como C# exemplo, tem tratamento especial de alguma forma. Mas não em específico, então talvez esse tratamento especial teria que ser específico. Ou seja, o compilador fazer algo específico no código com o tipo em específico, não só por uma característica dele.

Não gostava e ainda não gosto da ideia que o primitivo é por valor. Mas tem linguagem usa esta definição, até mesmo de forma dúbia. C# usava, mas não usa mais como sendo um tipo por valor, ou pelo menos um tipo por valor *built-in* (veja mais abaixo).

Não vi especificamente isso, mas poderia ser definido como tendo um literal especialmente tratado pelo compilador (tem linguagens que permitem criar literal no código). Não estou dizendo que é uma boa definição, mas é uma possível.

Mal dá para definir o que é um tratamento específico, porque até o *array* tem um literal. Ele é primitivo? Pode ser. Não costumo ver muita gente dizendo que é, mas parece ser sob certa definição. Uma lista que abstraia o *array* já não é, a não ser que ela também tenha um tratamento especial especifico, como o *array* tem. Muitas linguagens não definem o *array* como primitivo, mas *string* sim, aí eu não entendo mais nada.

Também já vi definição que é o tipo que não tem semântica específica. Mas isso quer dizer bem pouco e ainda dá margem à interpretação.

É tão triste que a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) possui uma definição. O verbete confunde com tipos nativos e com a ideia de ser *built-in* da linguagem. Ele é bem caótico.

Talvez *built-in* seja um sinônimo para primitivo, mas certamente ele é muito melhor, não dá para ter dúvida (eu acho) sobre ele ser algo que a linguagem traz nativamente, diferente do processador trazer nativamente. Meu entendimento é que tipos de biblioteca, mesmo a padrão, não são *built-in*, e não são primitivos. Pode ser que a implementação até seja feita também por biblioteca, mas, também, precisa ter o tratamento especial da linguagem.

O problema dessa definição é que o tipo `Object` costuma ter "especificação" de linguagem e geralmente ele costuma ser interpretado como oposto de primitivo. Então fico na dúvida. Pode ter alguma outra restrição. Por que `Object` não é primitivo e `String` é? Ambos são tipos por referência, mas um deles costuma ter semântica de valor.

Então tem que ser tipo por valor ou pelo menos ter essa semântica? Também?

Claramente o que é esse tratamento especial não é algo universal, cada tecnologia tem um critério diferente do que é primitivo.

Vi até os termos "primitivo numérico" (inclui o booleano?) e "primitivo textual" que inclui a *string*.

Algumas pessoas dizem que o oposto do tipo primitivo é o tipo composto, outros dizem que é o tipo construído por usuário (*user defined type*), mesmo que esse usuário, o programador, seja o cara que fez a biblioteca padrão. Olhando tudo aqui eu estou tendendo a preferir a segunda.

Em alguns, por coincidência o primitivo pode ser nativo ou atômico, mas não parece ser uma obrigatoriedade, caso contrário seria sinônimo.

Eu já vi gente chamando tipo primitivo de fundamental. Mas também vi usarem esse termo para tipos nativos. Fica difícil.

Eu gosto da definição "tipos que não são eles próprios construídos a partir da aplicação de regras a outros tipos", ainda que ela não resolva a questão inequivocamente.

Estou me posicionando como ele sendo mais o tratamento especial da linguagem de um jeito específico e não universal. Mas também acho ele menos relevante do que achava antes, então ele costuma ter pouca serventia para a computação. Evite o seu uso, sem ser um mala de brigar com quem usa errado, não tem problema usar informalmente, desde que todos entendam a mesma coisa. Se a comunidade aceita usar errado, use.

Como "tudo" o que é ruim, ele se tornou popular.

## Por valor

Não sei se encaixa bem aqui. Em geral esses tipos nativos, atômicos, escalares são por valor, os primitivos também, em certa definição, mas isso não é verdade absoluta. É verdade que um tipo por referência é composto pelo dado e pela referência, então por definição ele não pode ser nem nativo, nem atômico, nem escalar diretamente, e não pode ser primitivo, por certa definição. Sempre temos que tratar a *string* e qualquer tipo que tenha papel parecido como algo complicado, porque ele, em quase todos os casos, é um tipo por referência, certamente não nativo ou atômico e até primitivo, ou até mesmo escalar por algumas definições.

## Conclusão

Como exemplo, considere o tipo `BigInt` que algumas linguagens possuem. Geralmente é um tipo por referência. Não é nativo, sob algumas definições, não é naturalmente atômico, não costuma ser primitivo por qualquer definição (mas algumas linguagens poderiam fazê-lo assim, por alguma definição) e tem semântica escalar, mesmo sendo composto em sua implementação (em todos casos que eu analisei). Não é tão fácil assim classificar os tipo de dados.

Nem sempre o mais aceito é o mais correto. Eu não vou impor o que é mais correto.

Tem todo tipo de opinião sobre o que cada um é. Estou usando esta resposta para ajudar eu corrigir meus vícios e uniformizar minhas respostas daqui pra frente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).