# Taxonomicamente falando, quais as diferenças entre tipo, classe e categoria?

Tags: classes, terminologia, tipagem, taxonomia, ontologia

Por desconhecimento tenho a tendência de usar indistintamente os termos tipo, classe e categoria (acho que posso incluir aí os termos variedade e variação/variante) para quando desejo fazer algum tipo de sistematização ou categorização sobre qualquer assunto.

Quais são as diferenças entre eles e qual a forma correta de usar?

Não sei se a pergunta se encaixa bem no escopo de programação, mas de qualquer forma o uso correto dos termos deve ser útil no escopo de programação, como em outros escopos. Deve haver alguma relação entre os dois escopos, a qual eu gostaria de saber.

Por exemplo:

- Café e chá são *tipos* diferentes de bebidas.
- Gatos, tigres e leões são *tipos* de felinos.
- Gatos são *classificados* como felinos.
- Uma Ford Ranger pertence à *categoria* das caminhonetes.
- Goiabeira e limoeiro são *variedades* de árvores frutíferas.

Em programação:

- Uma classe (ou uma instância da classe) Cachorro é um tipo de Animal.
- Um tipo de dados inteiro de 64 bits.
- Categoria em computação é um termo taxonômico válido?

De repente é só uma pergunta para https://portuguese.stackexchange.com. :)

Há alguma maneira prática de determinar quando um termo é mais apropriado para uma determinada situação?

Pergunta semelhante em https://english.stackexchange.com/q/25713/188598

**EDITADO:**

Botei a preguiça de lado e dei uma olhada em dicionários (continua a dúvida da aplicabilidade em computação, estas interpretações são só para enriquecer a pergunta).

Aparentemente, tipo é o nome que se dá a um conjunto de traços ou características comuns a um grupo, ou a esse grupo em si, cujos membros possuem essas características em comum, ou ainda a um exemplar que representa esse grupo. Exemplos: o tipo dos números inteiros (em computação), o tipo dos portugueses, o tipo dos mulherengos, o tipo que assobia no banho, um tipo preguiçoso.

Podemos falar em subtipos, que são tipos secundários, que formam parte de um tipo primário mais geral. Os coronavírus são um subtipo dos vírus biológicos.

Note que pode haver intersecções nesta forma de classificar, e que pode haver hierarquias de tipos. O tipo dos "veículos de passeio" inclui diferentes modelos de veículos, e cada modelo também pode ser chamado de um tipo (o tipo dos Fuscas, que contém instâncias de Fuscas, ou o tipo dos Fuscas azuis, que contém instâncias de Fuscas azuis). Já o tipo dos "veículos vermelhos" não contém, mas apenas faz intersecção, com o tipo dos veículos de passeio.

Categorizar é dividir ideias em gêneros, espécies, etc., ou, em outras palavras, dividir pessoas ou coisas de maneira sistemática por critérios de aparência, qualidade, ou outros critérios quaisquer. Portanto, uma categoria é sinônimo de tipo ou subtipo (subtipo é um tipo de tipo, entendeu?), e categorizar é dividir em tipos. Ignoro como o termo é usado em computação.

A categoria dos "veículos leves" é uma categoria ou tipo que inclui os tipos de veículos esportivos, utilitários e picapes. Talvez o termo seja usado para se referir a um tipo primário, "pai" de alguns subtipos.

Já classificar significa colocar em ordem ou atribuir valor e tem a ver com o valor estimado para as coisas ou o padrão ao qual pertencem. Por isso se fala em classes sociais, em voos de primeira classe, à classe dos doutores ou dos mestres enxadristas. E, em computação, em hierarquias de classes (o que me traz uma certa confusão porque talvez sejam definidas em termos de genericidade/especificidade, mas aí poderia se tratar também de uma hierarquia de tipos).

Vejo então que o erro mais comum que cometo é usar o termo "classificar" como sinônimo de categorizar (embora não esteja de todo incorreto porque classe no dicionário pode ser sinônimo de categoria ou tipo).

Answer (score 1):

Eu posso responder em parte, porque é de programação/computação e porque é o que eu sei, o resto não, por um motivo ou outro.

Classe é uma forma de tipo, ou seja, na hierarquia taxonômica classe é uma especialização de tipo, assim como uma enumeração ou uma estrutura ou ainda uma interface também o são. O tipo abrange suas diversas formas.

Quais seriam as diversas formas que um tipo pode ter depende da tecnologia e tipagem dela, em alguns casos podemos ter tipos que são [primitivos ou nativos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575246/101), ou seja, não são tipos que você expressa como são compostos, mas já estão lá na tecnologia.

Então podemos ter classes como `Animal` e `Cachorro`, que são tipos, assim como um primitivo como um inteiro de 64 bits que é um tipo, mas não é uma classe, normalmente definido assim, mas poderia, conceitualmente algumas pessoas consideram como uma classe também, ainda que não seja definido como uma classe em código.

Tipo é uma generalização de como classificamos dados pelas características, enquanto a classe é uma forma específica que um desses dados possui. Então acho que podemos dizer que tipo é um termo mais conceitual, e classe é um pouco mais técnico, embora ambos são usados nos dois contextos e a forma exata de usar pode depender de onde está usando.

Erroneamente as pessoas intercambiam esses dois termos em algumas situações. Não é um erro quando diz que uma classe é um tipo, porque toda classe é um tipo mesmo.

E não acho que os termos podem ser interpretados de forma idêntica ao que se faz com outras taxinomias gerais, mas posso estar enganado.

Não sei dizer se são variações ou usam outra classificação taxonômica, mas existem tipos [por valor ou por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101) ou podem ser classificados como mutáveis e [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), entre outras classificações que não seguem uma hierarquia estrita, estamos falando de uma outra característica que não se encaixa na hierarquia normal dos termos.

Então se fosse criar uma hierarquia com os termos representados em código, teria problemas, as classes de orientação a objeto são limitadas para hierarquias simples e claras, uma das críticas que se faz à herança de OO.

Não posso ajudar muito com o termo categoria que é válido na computação, mas cai em uma área que eu não domino, talvez deveria.

Enquanto classes são mais usadas em OOP, categorias são mais usadas em programação funcional.

Não confundir a taxonomia criada em seus tipos com a taxinomia da computação.

Se quer saber sobre taxonomia geral, para ajudar interpretar um domínio e então criar tipos/classes adequadamente, aí acho a pergunta muito aberta e não condizente com o título.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).